# phpmyadmin: Can't change the value of the text if data is originally stored as an array

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, textfield

I've made a table with the following fields:

```
`id` type:INT,
`id_list`type:TEXT,
`name`type:VARCHAR(255).
```

`id` is my primary key.

From phpmyadmin 3.4.11.1deb2, I inserted a row:

```
(`null`, `'["1","2","3","4"]'`, `'TEST'`)
```

and it successfully saves to the table.

However, when I try to update the `id_list` field, instead of a text-field containing `["1","2","3","4"]`, I see a drop-down-list with each row equivalent to the text array that I stored.

Is this by design or a bug in the way that phpmyadmin is renders the resulting text?

[image]

I had to use a different table as an example, but notice the drop-down-list instead of a text-field.

Comment: now you got the score try adding the image, bcoz i tested works fine with mine

Comment: You are using an old version of phpMyAdmin, maybe try to update?

Comment: @Anamika I created a new table and inserted my example data and I too can make changes with a textfield, STRANGE.

I dynamically added the information in the image using a AJAX to PHP PDO script. The field is an array prepared with JSON.stringify().

$q = "INSERT INTO `schedules` (id, customer_id, employees, time_start, time_end) VALUES ('', :customer_id, :employees, :time_start, :time_end)";
$do = $db->prepare($q);

Comment: I just noticed that the customer_id field in the image is also experiencing the same problem. Shouldn't an INT type field be a text field and not a drop-down?

Comment: Could it be there's some links / relational data  in your `pmadb` which tells phpmyadmin the fields refer to other fields/rows/records? That'd do it afaik.... At least for the `TEXT` one, the `customer_id` could be a plain `FOREIGN KEY` perhaps.

Comment: may be problem is with the quotes, you are using "" in values and in your insert query also, and may be because of that you are facing issues. please add full code and echo the query you are working on

Comment: Thanks Wrikken, Anamika, it appears there is a relation set to both the customer_id and employees field. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have some relations between tables through these fields, as @Wrikken said in comments to your question.
I've used a pretty similar table structure, and also added one more table to reproduce the assumption I'm talking about:

> -- First table, similar to problem table
>
> CREATE TABLE `bars` (   `id` int(11),   `list` text,   `bar`
>   varchar(255),   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );
>
> INSERT INTO `bars` (`id`, `list`, `bar`) VALUES (1,
>   '["1","2","3","4"]', 'TEST');
>
> -- Second table, to reproduce the assumtion
>
> CREATE TABLE `foos` (   `id` int(11),   `foo` varchar(255),   PRIMARY
>   KEY (`id`) );
>
> INSERT INTO `foos` (`id`, `foo`) VALUES (1, 'foo1'), (2, 'foo2'), (3,
>   'foo3'), (4, 'foo4'), (5, 'foo5'), (6, 'foo6');

From scratch everything works fine as expected, i can edit TEXT field as text:

[image]

To reproduce 'dropdown' effect I've opened a problem `bars` table (with TEXT field) relations:

[image]

and have added a reference to `foos`, a table with possible ids, that are stored in `list` TEXT field as array:

[image]

Now when editing a record i have a dropdown instead of textarea for TEXT `list` field

[image]

So, try to check whether you have your TEXT field involved in any relations

*sorry, no rep to comment yet, so giving a complete answer that may not be a solution at all*

Comment: that appears to be it! Sadly, I am picking up this project from someone else. I've never dealt with field relations before, and I thank you and the community for the help.